# Outpost liasion simply won't go away. It has been years already!

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

**Context:**

1. I've been visited once by my Outpost Liason.
2. Nevermore any civilization traded with me.
3. I just found the Merchant stuck on a place of my Fortress.
4. I already broadened the way for it to go away, but it won't.
5. It seems that it got involved in a conflict when leaving, then the conflict ended and it simply don't know what to do anymore.

**Question:**

1. How to kick Urist McMerchant from my Fortress without killing him?

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can demolish the Trade Depot for it to go away, then build another one.